# Pop-out form for PHP with Zend

Tags: php, facebook

I use facebook sharer. and the link just opens a new tab. but I want to make it as pop out. I use PHP with Zend framework.

here are my codes:

```
<a name="fb_share" target="_blank" type="button" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=SOMETITLE&p[url]??=http://123.abc.com/&p[summary]=SOME DESCRIPTION">i-share on Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the JavaScript method to do this. The sharer is old and as been replaced with the Like button. The documentation for the JavaScript version can be [found here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).